# Image not displayed on JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am using below path to use the logo on my report.

```
/root/Reports/MyPractice/Logo.jpg
/root/Reports/MyPractice/MyLogoReport
```

The *jrxml* that I browsed inside MyLogoReport has the

```
<imageExpression><![CDATA["repo:/reports/MyPractice/Logo.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
```

When i run report on *JasperReports Server*. it doesn't show logo image

In *iReport* if i use `<imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Logo .jpg"]]></imageExpression>` it works on local.

Comment: Its Solved, changed the path.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized

Comment: Just confirm whether the path of image is correct or not its is written in red color below the image. usually we give name without image extension .jpg so try "repo:/reports/MyPractice/Logo"

Comment: Yes the issue was extension jpg.